# converting full date to short date

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm getting date from server like: Mon Mar 24 13:44:44 Asia/Calcutta 2014
I want to display it in shorter format may be like : Mar 24 13:44
Is there a way to do it like this? May be we can covert this string to get the desired format ?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "case");

            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
            query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);

            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                ParseObject image = (ParseObject) country.get("objectId");
                objectID = country.getObjectId();
                String cTitle = country.getString("caseTitle");
                String cDescription = country.getString("caseComment");
                String nameOfCreator = country.getString("name");
                createTime = String.valueOf(country.getCreatedAt());
                System.out.println("the created time is" + createTime);
```

output : Mon Mar 24 13:44:44 Asia/Calcutta 2014

Comment: Does the server *guarantee* that format? Is there any way of asking it to provide a more machine-friendly format?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried it but it has only this format to send the date and time :(

Comment: Well you could parse that format with SimpleDateFormat, but I'd be nervous of it changing. What server is this? Do you have any control over it? Documentation of the format?

Comment: @JonSkeet  I'm getting this date in a string variable (createTime )

Comment: Yes, I know - but that doesn't answer any of my questions...

Comment: @addy123 Jon Skeet is trying to tell you that having the time zone name embedded as text inside the string makes it difficult to parse. That is a terrible format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the trick:

```
String date="Mon Mar 24 13:44:44 Asia/Calcutta 2014";
String reqdate=date.substring(4,16);
```

it will return a string that start from index 4 and ends at 16 character but it will not take 16th character in the string it will stop at 15..as per requirement
and the reqdate will have Mar 24 13:44

Comment: its as per addy123 requirement

Comment: No it return Mar 24 13:44:44 as it starts from 4 and ends at 19 charater index

Comment: the start index is to be 4 and end index will be 16

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` to parse and `SimpleDateFormat.format()` to format dates as your like.

Comment: He has to transform the input string to a valid date first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class it can convert String to Date and `Vice-Versa`, you can set date in any format
eg.

`SimpleDateFormat x = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");` // this is important you must know // means MMM 'JUN' and not 'June' or 'Jun' 
`x.format(myDateObject);`// it will be 10-JUN-1991

Comment: I'm not able to use it .. can you explain how to use it with e.g. ?? Thnx

Comment: Well the difference between my code and your code should be the format in contructor only.
Try this 
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm");
It should work, if it doesnt then try changing the case like maybe hh:mm, but whta is written above should work

Comment: He has to transform the input string to a valid date first.

Comment: If your original Date i.e the big one is in String the first convert it to Date using same SimpleDateFormat Class.
To do that do this... Date myDateObject = simpleDateForObj.parse("Mon Mar 24 13:44:44 Asia/Calcutta 2014");
use PARSE method of SImpleDateFormat :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `"Mon Mar 24 13:44:44 Asia/Calcutta 2014"` is not a valid date string, so it can't be parsed